# Deinterlace by dropping even lines from command line

Tags: video, libav

I want to make an interlaced video with 50fps into a 25fps progressive, in the process i'm also reducing the size of the frame. Currently i am using avconv and there are deinterlacing options, however, they are not documented. So what i am afraid of is that they will actually start bleeding information i am trying to drop into the frames that i am trying to keep.

The only tool that i have found, that does a documented drop of even/odd frames is a plugin for AVIDemux, which unfortunately does not export into Ogg or even encode into Theora. When i attempt to dump into Huff codec (to not introduce quality loss due to reencoding) it demands that i split files at 4 GiB. So i can only use it for small videos.

Is there another tool that can help me?

Comment: You could always do the 4gigabyte split and then cut them back together after (assuming Huff codec supports append operations without re-encoding, I'm not familiar with that particular codec.)

Comment: @AJHenderson It is a possibility, and i was already looking at that, but it's a hack. I think i would rather try to figure out the avlib's code and create a 'drop-deinterlacer', but i was hoping that something like that already exists.

Comment: yeah, makes sense.  I unfortunately have near 0 experience with AVIDemux or avlib.  I'm an Adobe/Windows guy, just a few little things when I was working on writing programs to work with video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg -i input -vf field,scale=123:456 output` will do the trick, where 123:456 is your x:y frame dimensions for the output. The field filter just chucks away the fields it doesn't use. Documention on the field filter [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#field). Note that you'll need extra stuff in the command to get good results - e.g. you'll probably want to specify codec details and so on.

Comment: Will give you 50 rep for this when the system permits me to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf framestep=2 output
```

This will output every second frame.

Comment: That doesn't actually do what is expected with the progressive video. The result is still the same vertical resolution, so it doesn't drop unneeded lines.